# iPhone Contacts - Get Company Name

Tags: ios, addressbook

I am using the Address Book frameworks in an iPhone app, and I would like to get the items Company Name. I can't find this info in the AddressBookUI_Framework.pdf, can someone shed some light on this.

> AddressBook/AddressBook.h
>
> AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `kABPersonOrganizationProperty` key.

Comment: Thanks, I was searching "Company"

Comment: Easy to get lost searching for "Company" as it is named `kABPersonOrganizationProperty`.

Answer (score 1):

As Ole mentioned you need to use kABPersonOrganizationProperty key. You can have a look at [ABPerson](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html) reference and ABPerson.h header for other keys and more details.